# Remove multiple parameters and rewrite url Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite the following Url for SEO and userfriendly purposes using htaccess or other solution. I have searched and found many answers but none gives me multiple parameters and i am not advance at this.

`mysite.com/myfile.php?dept=1&prodid=161&user=2018&ulevel=1&parentcust=1&prodname=My widget`

to

`mysite.com/products/mywidget`

if My Widget has spaces or apostrophes i need them removed. example the product `Tiger's eye widget` should be `tigerseyewidget` or `tigers-eye-widget`

Comment: So your `myfile.php` script doesn't care about all that other stuff (dept, prodid, user, ulevel, etc)?

Comment: yes it does care about them and need them. isnt it possible to rewrite the url while still be able to get those variables in the script? More like how Joomla does it when you rewrite the URL

Comment: If that information isn't in the URL, where would they come from?

Comment: Maybe my questions isnt clear.. if i check my joomla url it is `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=240` but whats is index in google and the browser is `mysite.com/myarticle.html`. That is wht i want to achieve

Comment: Then you need to change your script so that it knows when you get `mywidget` as the request, to populate all that other stuff that you need. Joomla has some mapping that it knows "myarticle.html" is id=240 and is an article. You need to create such a mapping if you want your URLs to look that way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to solve your problem with rewrites only.

For starters, let's strip your query string:

- user id & user level do not belong there - it's dangerous to have these in your query string. What if I change it in my browser to user=1&ulevel=5 - am I then suddenly the administrator with access to all area's? Instead, work with sessions and store the user id & ulevel there
- Do you really need the product id as well as the product name in the query string? I'd say: drop the product name, the id should be enough information for you to retrieve the product name.
- parentcust: what is that? Do you really need it in the query string? What if I change the value? Looks like something that belongs in a session as well.

After stripping that, all you're left with is myfile.php?dept=1&prodid=161 - now that's something that's much easier to rewrite!

How to rewrite is another question. There are plenty examples on SO how to rewrite a query string based request to a "pretty url". Changing `Tiger's eye widget` to `tigers-eye-widget` is also well documented.

But.. who generates these links? If you generate these links, why not turn it around and link your products to e.g. mysite.com/tigers-eye-widget.html and then in PHP map "tigers-eye-widget.html" to product id 161 & dept 1?

Your problem should really only apply to legacy URL's that people may have bookmarked or still appear in search results. But for those cases it's perfectly acceptable to redirect them instead of rewriting them. So you can keep the mapping in a database or textfile, process the request with PHP and do a 301 redirect to the new URL - that way you tell search engines to replace the old URL with the new one and you don't have to worry about complicated multiple .htaccess rewrite rules.

Comment: none of those security concerns matters nor are they valid. Thanks very much though for the concern.  i have clients linking to my db and those inputs are required. however on the client website those pages are not being indexed by google for obvious reasons and i wanted a solution to fix that.